# Data Bound event for a TwwDBGrid

Tags: delphi, ado

I'm trying to resize a TwwDBGrid column, specifically for a pixel-width which I understand to be something like:

```
myGrid.ColWidths[1] := 50; // 50 pixels
```

However, this doesn't appear to work. My thought is I am trying to apply it too early in the grid's lifecycle. Which leads to the following question:

At what point is the grid bound and how can I connect into the end of the databound lifecycle?

I am binding the grid at runtime as follows:

```
myDataSource.DataSet := dataset01; //TADQuery
myGrid.DataSource := myDataSource;
i := myDataSource.DataSet.FieldCount; // myGrid.FieldCount;
```

The dataset is opened prior to assigning it to the grid. The values are populated to the grid as expected and the edit capabilities appear to work fine. However, myGrid.FieldCount says zero (0) at this point where myDataSource.DataSet.FieldCount says five (5) at this point. This is the end of the subroutine.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. When dealing with a DBGrid, your primary interaction should be the attached DataSet. If you need to work with the columns in the grid (and not the *data* in that column), use the `DBGrid.Columns` collection. So if you need to change column 1's width, use `myGrid.Columns[1].Width`.

Comment: There is no .Width property (using the TwwDBGrid) but there is a DisplayWidth property which, if I understand correctly, is the width in approx. # of chars whereas ColWidths is in pixels.

Comment: Your question makes no mention of `TwwDBGrid`. You said *a Delphi Grid column*, and there is no indication in any of the content or tags to indicate anything different. If your question is about something else entirely, it should clearly state that in the question.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I clarified my question: At what point is the grid bound and how can I connect into the end of the databound lifecycle?